# Transformer, and Resistance Probelm

Tags: transformer, multimeter

Is it possible to test the pins of a transformer using the resistance part of the multi-meter?  I was testing a 6 pin transformer, and resistances measured

> 4.1 Ohms between two pins connected to a copper winding
>
> 4.2 Ohms between two pins I think are connected to each other
>
> 952 Ohms between a pin in the bottom of the transformer, and a stray wire

[image: Transformer]
[image: Transformer bottom]

The bottom pins, closest to the table are connected to the copper winding.  The two pins closest to the magnet  are connected to each other.  The black stray wire is connected to the lonely wire in the bottom.  Why is there since a huge resistance in the output of the transformer?

Comment: The thickness of the insulation on the "stray" wire hints at the answer : the high resistance winding generates a very high voltage.

Comment: @BrianDrummond That was my original guess but I said probably it doesn't have to do with the insulation.

Comment: That winding is many turns of very thin wire. Simple as that.

Comment: Adding to what Brian Drummond said. This looks like a CRT flyback transformer that converts maybe a few hundred volts at the primary to maybe 15-25KV at the secondary. The stray wire is part of the secondary that typically goes to the anode on the body of a CRT through a diode.